# How to run as admin only one line in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, wireshark, runas

this is my first question here, so when criticizing anything, please try to be constructive.

I am trying to make my portable version of Wireshark work using one batch (.bat) file. This is my current code:

```
@echo on
@echo _wireshark is starting_
@echo ...
@echo off
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c sc stop npf"
start "" /wait WiresharkPortable.exe
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c sc stop npf"
@echo on
@echo _Thanks for sniffing around_
@echo _Bye now.
@pause
```

There is a problem with ***runas*** lines, supposedly they open new cmd window, but ***sc stop npf*** is not executed (checked with ***cmd /k*** option).

Could anyone help me find my mistake?

Regards,
Michal

Comment: Fix your question title please.  It should be a question...

Comment: `runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c pause"` <--- test this to see what happens.

Comment: Now that I read your question title - you know what the problem is.  You don't have sufficient permissions to run `sc.exe`

Comment: New cmd-window opened with message "Press any key to continue..." - so it is working OK. My line, however is still not working properly. The aim is to 1) be able to open wireshark using one .bat file; 2) this file should start npf service, run wireshark, wait until it is closed and unload npf driver. Just wanted to mention that the whole procedure works fine when is done step-by-step manually.

Comment: I don't? My username, Michal, has admin privileges.

Comment: Did you notice that you have `"cmd /c sc stop npf"` in both commands?  If that is not the issue then right click the batch file and run as admin, to test this - I assume it's Vista or later.  An Admin account doesn't have full privileges by default.

Comment: It is Win8.1. Thanks @foxidrive for spotting my error. Also I was trying to put commands in separate files - they work when I right click and run them as admin, but they don't when I call them from my batch file. I used then:
`runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c sc_start.bat"`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really don't need to put @ before every line, really you only need it at the beginning

`@ echo off                                                                                          :: rest of code here`

So instead of typing @ before everything, I would type

```
@echo off
echo _wireshark is starting_
echo ...
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c sc stop npf"
start "" /wait WiresharkPortable.exe
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Michal "cmd /c sc stop npf"
echo _Thanks for sniffing around_
echo _Bye now.
pause
```

I would also delete any unnecessary `@echo on(off)` commands throughout, one, because it makes it quicker and easier to type, two, it looks neater.

You also might want to do `pause>nul` that is just my preference, so it's not that important in all honesty.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips. They do not, however, solve my initial problem.